# Is it possible not to queue tasks if Redis is not available for some reason?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I use the Laravel Horizon. And it happens that Redis is unavailable for some reason.

Is it possible not to queue tasks if Redis is not available for some reason?

Of course, I can catch an exception `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException` when I queue a task. But I have a lot of tasks in very different parts of the code, and I would not like to wrap each one in an try-catch block. Can I globally tell the horizon not to queue tasks if Redis is not available?

Comment: _"Or how can I catch an exception"_ - There's nothing special about that exception, you catch it just like any other. Read more about exceptions and how to handle them [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: @M.Eriksson of course, I meant the ability to catch exceptions not at the very moment of queuing the task, but at a more global level. I would not like to wrap all the lines where the tasks are set in a try-catch. I would like to do this somehow more globally in order to solve my main question - not to queue tasks if radish is not available.

Comment: You would only need to wrap the connection in a try/catch. If you get an exception, abort the rest of the script (or take any other appropriate action). No need for having "everything" in a try/catch. If that doesn't answer your question, then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73137718/edit) the question and include an example of an actual use case (since it then would be very unclear what your actual issue/question is)

Comment: I edited. Of course, I can catch an exception `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException` when I queue a task. But I have a lot of tasks in very different parts of the code, and I would not like to wrap each one in an try-catch block. Can I globally tell the horizon not to queue tasks if Redis is not available?